# Reduce initialization of dictionary elements via pattern

Tags: f#

Is there a way I could use a pattern to initialize a dictionary?

For example, instead of naming each key-value pair like the following:

[0, true; 1, true; 2, true; 3,true; 4,true]

How could I do something like:

[0, true; .. 4, true]

**NOTE:**

I know nothing about F# so I apologize if my question sounds stupid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let dictionary = [ for i in 1..4 -> i, true ] |> Map.ofSeq
```